# Powershell array: does not contain a method named Contains

Tags: powershell

I have this Powershell code:

```
$find_filesize = @(123, 395, 4929, 92345)
#$fpath is a file item
$fsize = (Get-Item $fpath).length
if ( $find_filesize.Contains($fsize) ) { 
... }
```

But it returns this error:

```
Method of invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Contains'.
At powershell.ps1:4
+ if ( $find_filesize.Contains($fsize) ) {
```

I've also tried:

```
[]int32[]]$$find_filesize = 123, 395, 4929, 92345
```

But that gives the same error.

What am I missing? From what I understand, I am defining it as an array.

Comment: Either close or remove the paren on the `$fsize = (Get-Item $fpath.length`, and then see if you're still getting errors.

Comment: This might help: [Why can't i call Contains method from my array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931035/why-cant-i-call-contains-method-from-my-array)....  Have you tried `if ($find_filesize -contains $fsize)`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That's a typo in the post, corrected it.

Comment: The `Contains()` method seems to require PowerShell v3 or later.

Comment: That's true @rokumaru, but the method literally cannot be used against an array. You can use the operator (which is cleaner and easier.)

Comment: @rad_ In v2, as you say, the `-contains` operator should be used. 
Since an array in v3 or later have the `bool IList.Contains(System.Object value)` method, you can use either.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$find_filesize = @(123, 395, 4929, 92345)
#$fpath is a file item
$fsize = (Get-Item $fpath).length
if ( $find_filesize -match $fsize ) { 
... }
```

You could do it with the `contains` operator as well. I always choose `match` as my go-to operator though. You cannot call a contains method on an array.

Comment: The following cases are confusing, so I do not recommend using the `-match` operator on arrays in conditional expression of if statements. `if((0,2,3) -match 0) { "foo" } else { "bar" }`

Comment: How is it confusing? In certain situations you’re obviously going to use contains. Match is great in this scenario considering the numbers are unique...

Comment: It doesn't matter if the numbers are unique.   In the above case, many people expect the output to be `"foo"`, but in fact it is `"bar".`

The `-match` operator works as a filter when used on an array.    as the output of `(0,2,3) -match 0` is `0`, the output of `if (0) {" foo "} else { "bar" }` is `"bar"`.

Comment: No it's not? The condition is true so it's not going to even touch `else`? Where did you get this ideology from? I literally use this structured statement in many of my scripts and have NEVER had this type of condition occur... Please provide sources on what makes you think this is what is occurring.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6

Comment: > When the input to an operator is a scalar value, comparison operators return a Boolean value. When the input is a collection of values, the comparison operators return any matching values. If there are no matches in a collection, comparison operators do not return anything.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you on something that you are making zero sense out of. You're stating arbitrary responses to try and defend your claim. Why don't you try your pseudo code in an IDE and tell me it doesn't return your `foo` output. The link you provide again proved my point by the way. `-match Returns true when string matches regex`

Comment: https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzNNQ8NAx0jHWFNBNzexJDlDwUBToVpBKS0/X0mhViE1pzgVxE1KLAJy//8HAA

Comment: In addition to the above, you should not use the `-match` operator to compare numbers. The reason is that the `-match` operator takes input as a string and detects a match with a regular expression. The following example outputs `"foo"`.  `if ((123,395) -match 39) { "foo" } else { "bar" }`